# SizedQueue.clear does not free push

Tags: ruby, multithreading

The code below is a simplification of a much bigger and complex code, what happens is when I invoke the stop function and do a queue clear I was expecting the lock on the get_new thread to be free and ending the whole thread, instead what happens its a dead lock on the thread.join statement.

If I do a pop instead of clear the desired behavior happens. Can you help me understand why?

```
class Controller
        require 'thread'
        require 'monitor'
        require 'net/http'

    attr_accessor :thread_count, :event_queue, :is_running, :producer_thread, :events

    def initialize
        @thread_count = 5
        @event_queue = SizedQueue.new(@thread_count)
        @events = [27242233, 27242232,27242231]
    end

    def start
        @is_running = true
        @producer_thread = Thread.new{get_new()}
    end

    def get_new
        while @is_running do
            @events.each do |e|
                p e.to_s
                @event_queue << e
            end
            sleep 1
        end
        p "thread endend"
    end



    def stop
        p "Stoping!"
        @event_queue.clear
        p "Queue size: " + @event_queue.length.to_s
        sleep 2
        @is_running = false
        sleep 2
        producer_thread.join
        puts "DONE!"
    end
end

service = Controller.new
service.start
sleep 5
service.stop
```

Comment: What version/patch level of ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I don't know if this is an expected behavior, if it is, what is another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9342) in ruby. It is fixed in ruby [1.9.3p545](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_3_545/ChangeLog).

Early versions of ruby 2.1 and 2.0 were affected too. For those you want 2.1.2 or 2.0.0p481 respectively